# Getting average of values in a field based on variable in another field

Tags: text-processing, awk

Is there a way to get average of values in a field based on variables in another field? For example for the following input

```
a x 3
b y 4
a y 2
b x 5
b x 20
```

I want this output

```
a 2.5
b 9.67
```

I found this awk script to get average for values in a column

```
awk '{ total += $3; count++ } END { print total/count }' file.txt
```

but how can I add for loop in it to have the average for every variable in column 1?

The file is tab-separated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html) is also handy for tasks like this ex.

```
$ mlr --nidx stats1 -a mean -f 3 -g 1 file.txt
a 2.500000
b 9.666667
```

or (with a more recent version that has the `format-values` verb)

```
$ mlr --nidx stats1 -a mean -f 3 -g 1 then format-values -f '%.2f' file.txt
a 2.50
b 9.67
```

Answer (score 7):

You're not too far off. Try arrays indexed by `$1`:

```
awk '{ total[$1] += $3; count[$1]++ } END {for (t in total) print t, total[t]/count[t]}' file
a 2.5
b 9.66667
```

Or, if you want a maximum of two decimal points, as you show in your question:

```
$ awk '{ total[$1] += $3; count[$1]++ } END {for (t in total) printf "%s %.2f\n", t, total[t]/count[t]}' file
a 2.50
b 9.67
```

Comment: @terdon:  Why not just define `OFMT="%.2f"` ? And, BTW, two decimal places were not requested for `2.5`.

Comment: I've been using `awk` for decades, and I wasn't aware of `OFMT`, I've always used `printf` for things like this. But I'm also often creating fixed-size fields to align columns.

Comment: FWIW I've been aware of OFMT for decades but as far as I can recall have never used it as there's never been a time when I wanted to have the same floating point display value apply to multiple print statements throughout my code and if you don't have that then there's no benefit to setting OFMT as your code is clearer if you just specify the format in the printf formatting string.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `datamash`:

```
$ datamash -R2 -W -s -g 1 mean 3 <file
a       2.50
b       9.67

$ datamash -W -s -g 1 mean 3 <file
a       2.5
b       9.6666666666667
```

- `-R2` round to two decimal places
- `-W` use spaces and/or tabs as field separators
- `-s` sort before grouping
- `-g 1` group on the first field
- `mean 3` mean of the values, third field

You can remove `-W` if you have tabs as separators add `--output-delimiter=' '` if you want to replace tabs with space characters in the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
   #!/bin/bash
counta=`awk '$1 ~ /^a$/{print NR}' filename| awk 'END{print NR}'`
countb=`awk '$1 ~ /^b$/{print NR}' filename| awk 'END{print NR}'`

awk -v counta="$counta" '{if ($1 == "a"){sum=sum+$NF}}END{print "a" " " sum/counta}'  filename

awk -v countb="$countb" '{if ($1 == "b"){sum=sum+$NF}}END{print "b" " " sum/countb}'  filename
```

output

```
a 2.5
b 9.66667
```